# Multiprocessing to read files and append to list in python

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a large set of individual files and I am trying to read them and append them to one npy file. To speed up the process, I want to use multiprocessing. Following is the code I wrote based on some discussions I found here. However, the speed is almost the same as reading the files one by one without multiprocessing. Is it limited by the I/O speed of my disk or is there anything wrong with my code? Thanks a lot for your help.

Updates: The process was done on a cluster. I checked the I/O speed for a simple `cp -r directory directory` command, it can go up to 1GB/s. But my code below only goes to 200 mb/s. In other words, it might not be limited by the I/O speed. Could anyone check if my code is written correctly?

```
import numpy as np
import os, re
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pool
import multiprocessing


def compressFile(inputs, targets, lock, rootdir, filename):
    with lock:
        data = np.load(os.path.join(rootdir, filename))
        inputs.append(data)
        targets.append('a' in filename) # a second list to store something about the file name


if __name__ == '__main__':

    rootdir = 'directory'

    with Manager() as manager, Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:

        lock = manager.Lock()
        inputs = manager.list()
        targets = manager.list()
        file_list = [f for f in os.listdir(rootdir) if '.npy' in f]
        pool.starmap(compressFile, zip(repeat(inputs), repeat(targets), repeat(lock), repeat(rootdir), file_list))

        np.save(os.path.join(rootdir, 'inputs.npy'), np.asarray(inputs))
        np.save(os.path.join(rootdir, 'targets.npy'), np.asarray(targets))
```

Comment: Yes, it is limited by the speed of your disk. The only thing you are doing in the subprocess is reading and unpickling a file; and unless you are using a RAM drive, the former is so much slower than the latter that multiprocessing is possibly even hurting, instead of helping. Multiprocessing, by definition, only helps when your process depends on the _processor_.

Answer (score 0):

Read files can only be executed concurrently when they are placed outside the lock. if this is only an IO operation. It may be faster to use the thread pool.
but the parsing file to npy also needs to be calculated. You can compare the thread pool and the process pool who executes faster

```py
import numpy as np
import os, re
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pool
import multiprocessing


def compressFile(inputs, targets, lock, rootdir, filename):
    data = np.load(os.path.join(rootdir, filename))
    with lock:
        
        inputs.append(data)
        targets.append('a' in filename) # a second list to store something about the file name


if __name__ == '__main__':

    rootdir = 'directory'

    with Manager() as manager, Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:

        lock = manager.Lock()
        inputs = manager.list()
        targets = manager.list()
        file_list = [f for f in os.listdir(rootdir) if '.npy' in f]
        pool.starmap(compressFile, zip(repeat(inputs), repeat(targets), repeat(lock), repeat(rootdir), file_list))

        np.save(os.path.join(rootdir, 'inputs.npy'), np.asarray(inputs))
        np.save(os.path.join(rootdir, 'targets.npy'), np.asarray(targets))
```